# Received memory warning. Level=2

Tags: ipad, memory-management, webserver

i want to get 6 Mb (Html file size)Data from web service.Its run fine on Simulator but when i run that application on ipad its give me an error Received memory warning. Level=2.

Comment: You get error while downloading or displaying file?

Comment: How About if i download 600 page of Html

Answer (score 0):

You can download the PDF to your computer, shrink its size by compressing the images, and then host the smaller version yourself.

The easiest way to shrink the PDF file is: in Adobe Acrobat Pro 9, click on the "Document" tab and then choose "Reduce file size..." (source: the first comment of http://www.ehow.com/how_4937702_reduce-pdf-file-size-easily.html)

Also see: http://blog.nitropdf.com/index.php/2008/02/11/5-tricks-to-shrinkreduce-pdf-file-size/